# Website specific UserID display/remembering

Tags: display

Until recently, I could open a website and my userID was displayed, by default. However, now I don't see the userID (depending upon the website) at all. I believe, Chrome developers have made some changes/updates that is causing this. Now, I have keep remembering 100s of these UserIDs if I have to continue to use Chrome, which is a BIG PAIN.

Comment: You did not ask a question.... Are you talking about Auto-fill? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop Another option is to use a password manager like Bitwarden

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.